# Scrollto is getting stuck and not scrolling to the top of the page after a modal toggles off

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with a bunch of cards the user can select.  There is a button on each card which invokes a modal to collect a bit of data.  A button on the modal then invokes some javascript which does some stuff with the data then invokes

```
window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

This tries to work, the animation starts but the top isn't reached.  The card that the initial button was pressed on seems to make the scroll get stuck.  It works fine when a modal isn't invoked and the button click on the card invokes scrollTo.
I suspect it must something to do with the animation of the modal toggling off getting in the way but I've tried every which way and I can't seem sort it out.

If you scroll to the bottom of the cards and try here, you'll see what I mean https://www.codeply.com/p/cUR1SYNdjN

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Did you check the console ? You have an error that is risen on button click (a button that open a modal): `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. I think the issue is caused by `onclick="@onclickModal"`.

Comment: It's not that - I just stripped out some code to simplify the example and forgot to pull out the onclick attribute.  I've updated the codeply to prove it.